# Cloud code logs not showing in parse-dashboard

Tags: parse-platform

I am able to run `parse-server` on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and run locally the `parse-dashboard` with local NodeJS however Cloud Code logs does not show up even if in the settings it is configured:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || '', // Add the file key to provide access to files already hosted on Parse
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

What could be missing in the configuration?

Here's the code that I am expecting to log:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  console.log('hello method called');
  res.success('Hi');
});
```

I can see from my sample website that the method return the correct response but logs does not show in the parse-dashboard.

Comment: is the cloud code running? it should not show up in the dashboard... why it should?

Comment: Even the logs are not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its nothing that you can do in the configuration. The CloudCode is currently not meant to be shown in the Parse Dashboard but Parse Community is working on it. See and follow that issue (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/895) and as soon its closed you might be able to view the cloude code on Parse Dashboard.